# How to put php syntax on cms page in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

How can I put a php code on cms page in Magento?

Image here: http://screencast.com/t/COgHigLih7

I want to put

```
<?php
 echo "Test";
?>
```

Comment: may i know why you want to add php code in static page ? is you want to change dynamically ?

Comment: Create a block and a phtml file.

Call this block and phtml in cms page. Check any site home page cms code to get idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can not add php code directly into the content of a cms page

What you could do is add your php code into a pthml and then call it from you cms page

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/my_php_code.phtml"}}
```